# Cloudflare's bypass cache page rule not working

Tags: caching, cloudflare

I have this page, where users upload their images: http://ho96.com/yiimarket/uploader/image/index

I want to disable Cloudflare cache in this page, so I added the following rule:

```
*ho96.com/yiimarket/uploader*
```

But it's not working at all. What's happening?

Cache only works when I add this rule:

```
*ho96.com/*
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a "/" after uploader but before the *

```
*ho96.com/yiimarket/uploader/*
```

We recently created some helpful demo videos to walk through this and other types of rules.  http://www.cloudflare.com/features-page-rules